# Convert slash to tilde as Url Separator

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, laravel

I have a question how we can separate Url with slash in place of slash
For example i have a URL like:

1st case

```
www.domain.com/category/category_id
 then URL shown would be 
www.domain.com/category~category_id
```

2nd case

```
 www.domain.com/category/subcategory/category_id
 then URL shown would be 
 www.domain.com/category/subcategory~category_id
```

So we would be separating Url when we have situation like this and only last segment would be affected. How we can do this in Php. I am trying to do this thing in Laravel! Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: and why do you need to this?!?!

Comment: Working on client project and  this is his need @CodeBird

Answer (score 0):

1. create .htaccess in your www root and put this into it:

   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [QSA]
2. in index.php use this to get params:

   ...
   $params = explode('/', $_GET['params']);
   $lastTwo = explode('~', $params[count($params) - 1]);
   if (count($lastTwo) == 2) {
     $params[count($params) - 1] = $lastTwo[0];
     $params[] = $lastTwo[1];
   }
   ...

Now you have all params as array and you can process it.

Comment: You have changed my question . I don't want to get params. i need to change url structure from slash to tilde as asked

Comment: So I don't understand what do you want. Is it about generating URLs or you want to redirect from someting.com/one/two/three to something.com/one/two~three ?

Comment: I want to show url in something.com/one/two~three form instead of something.com/one/two/three. publically this url would be shown

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^~]+?)/([^/~\s]+)/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/~]+)/?$ /$1~$2 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^([^~]+)(.+)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Is their a way where my working platform would get these url in slash and show them on tilde only? Because by using this url will be changed but then my working platform i.e laravel starts unrecognizing the url. Hence 404 is throwned.

Comment: Any particular reason you want tilde replacing last slash?

Comment: Well I don't know the reasoning behind that and I don't know Laravel good enough to tell you anything about that. I am suggesting you an additional rule that will rewrite it back to without slash internally.

Comment: Yes i can see that!! I have to research on that!! anyway thanx for your help man!